# If $g(x)$ is the maximum value of $f(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and define a function $g(x)$ on $[a,b]$ as follows

$g(a)=f(a)$  and for $a \lt x \le b$ then $g(x)$ be the maximum value of $f(t)$ on $[a,x]$. Prove that $g(x)$ is continuous of $[a,b]$.

I was following along with an example in the text that I have that states

If $f$ and $g$ are continuous real functions on $[a,b]$ which are differentiable in $(a,b)$ then there is a point $x \in (a,b)$ at which

$$[f(b)-f(a)]g'(x) = [g(b)-g(a)]f'(x)$$

the proof is the "generalized mean value theorem" I was wondering if it was ok to use it in this case and where it would apply in the question.

Comment: You can't use the generalised mean value theorem to answer the original question, since you don't know that the $f$ and $g$ from the original question are differentiable (you only know continuous).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to keep in mind when answering this question.

1. If $f(t)$ does not increase after some point $t = t_0$ then $g(t) = g(t_0)$ for $t \geq t_0$. Since lines are continuous, $g(t)$ must be continuous on this segment. On the image below, this is represented by the red line on the interval $(0.2, 0.7)$.
2. Because $f(t)$ was continuous up to $t_0$, $g(t)$ must be as well, and thus is continuous from $0$ until the end of the horizontal line segment.
3. If $f(t)$ increases to a value greater than its value at $t_0$, then there must first exist a value $t_1 \geq t_0$ such that $f(t_1) = f(t_0)$. That is, it must first pass through the old maximum value (because $f(t)$ is continuous). This is represented by the behaviour of the red line around the value $0.75$.

With these two points in mind, the main part of the proof is to show that, roughly: if $f(t)$ 'dips down and comes back up again', then $g(t)$ 'meets back up' with $f(t)$. How could we frame this using the definition of a continuous function? Note that this works without reference to a compact interval.

[image: A plot of $f(t) = t\cos(2\pi t)$ on $t\in[0,1]$ and $g(t) := \max_{0\leq x \leq t} f(x)$.]

Above: a plot of $f(t) = t\cos(2\pi t)$ on $t\in[0,1]$ and $g(t) := \max_{0\leq x \leq t} f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence converging to $x \in [a,b]$. It has a monotonic subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ (also converging to $x$), which we assume to be non-decreasing (the opposite case is similar). Then the sequence $\{g(x_{n_k})\}$ is non-decreasing and bounded above by $g(x)$, so it converges to its supremum $L$ (say).

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $L < g(x)$. As $[a,x]$ is compact, there is some $p \le x$ such that $f(p) = \max\limits_{u \in [a,x]} f(u) = g(x)$. We cannot have $p < x$ for then $g(x) = f(p) \le g(p) \le g(x_{n_k}) \le L$ for some $x_{n_k} \in (p, x)$.

So we have $p = x \Rightarrow f(x) = g(x)$. As $f$ is continuous, there exists by IVT a point $q < x$ so that $L < f(q) < f(x)$. But then $L < f(q) \le g(q) \le g(x_{n_k}) \le L$ for some $x_{n_k} \in (q, x)$, again a contradiction. Conclude that $L = g(x)$, so $g$ is continuous at $x$.